# Android FileNotFoundException with app first running with use Thread

Tags: android, file-io

When downloading .csv file using ftp on Android, I get a FileNotFoundException error at the first execution. (No problem from the second)

I think an error when trying to open a file before downloading it completely.
But I do not know how to solve the problem. How can I fixed it? ToT

Library used : commons-net-3.6.jar(https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi)

LoadingActivity.java

```java
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static int[] imageId;
    static int[] allImageId;
    static JSONObject object;  // final obj
    JSONArray array;    // datainfo > json
    JSONObject dataInfo;    // 
    ArrayList<Data> dataList;

    static JSONObject allObject;  // final obj
    JSONArray allArray;    // datainfo > json
    JSONObject allDataInfo;    // 
    ArrayList<AllData> allDataList;

    Intent intent;

    String[] FileName = {"first.csv", "second.csv"};
    String FileExtend = ".csv";
    String fileURL = "http://ipaddress/ftpaccount/ftp/files/";
    String SavePath;
    String SaveFolder = "/files";

    DownloadThread mThread;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);

        SavePath = getFilesDir().getPath() + SaveFolder;
        setImageResource();

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("isFirst", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isFirst = pref.getBoolean("isFirst", false);
        if (isFirst == false) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isFirst", true);
            editor.commit();
            // first run
            for (int i = 0; i < FileName.length; i++) {
                File dir = new File(SavePath);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdir();
                }
                mThread = null;
                if (new File(SavePath + "/" + FileName[i]).exists() == false) {
                    mThread = new DownloadThread(fileURL + "/" + FileName[i], SavePath + "/" + FileName[i]);
                    mThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
        readData();
        readAllData();
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("cardData", dataList);
        intent.putExtra("cardAllData", allDataList);
//        startActivity(intent);
//        finish();
    }

    public void readData() {
        object = new JSONObject();
        array = new JSONArray();
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(SavePath + "/" + FileName[0]);
            while(is != null) {

            }
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr, ',', '"', 0);
            String[] data;
            int i = 0;
            while ((data = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                dataInfo = new JSONObject();

                dataInfo.put("cardNo", data[0]);
                dataInfo.put("cardName", data[1]);
                dataInfo.put("cardEngName", data[2]);
                dataInfo.put("keyword", data[3]);
                dataInfo.put("comment1", data[4]);
                dataInfo.put("comment2", data[5]);
                dataInfo.put("comment3", data[6]);
                dataInfo.put("comment4", data[7]);
                dataInfo.put("comment5", data[8]);
                dataInfo.put("comment1_rev", data[9]);
                dataInfo.put("comment2_rev", data[10]);
                dataInfo.put("comment3_rev", data[11]);
                dataInfo.put("comment4_rev", data[12]);
                dataInfo.put("comment5_rev", data[13]);
                Data cardData = new Data(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6], data[7], data[8],
                        data[9], data[10], data[11], data[12], data[13]);
                dataList.add(cardData);

                array.put(i, dataInfo);
                i++;
            }
            object.put("data", array);

            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class DownloadThread extends Thread {
        String ServerUrl;
        String LocalPath;

        DownloadThread(String serverPath, String localPath) {
            ServerUrl = serverPath;
            LocalPath = localPath;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            URL url;
            int Read;
            try {
                url = new URL(ServerUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                int len = conn.getContentLength();
                byte[] tempByte = new byte[len];
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                File file = new File(LocalPath);
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                for (; ; ) {
                    Read = is.read(tempByte);
                    if (Read <= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    os.write(tempByte, 0, Read);
                }
                is.close();
                os.close();
                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            afterDown.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }

        Handler afterDown = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // progress
            }
        };
    }

    public void setImageResource() {
        imageId = new int[]{R.drawable. ... };
        allImageId = new int[]{R.drawable. ... };
    }
```

and Logcat error log

```
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.testapp/files/files/first.csv (No such file or directory)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:99)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at com.example.tarot.LoadingActivity.readData(LoadingActivity.java:130)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at com.example.tarot.LoadingActivity.onCreate(LoadingActivity.java:116)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.884 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.885 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.885 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
2019-03-27 17:57:18.885 16755-16755/com.example.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask), and think about onPostExecute to handle downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

In your line of code here

```
 if (new File(SavePath + "/" + FileName[i]).exists() == false) {
   //create the folder Savepath first
}
```

it checks if the file doesn't exist and then tries to download to that same folder.
Create the folder if it doesn't exist first and then try to write to that location.